# Restore Teamcity

Tags: linux, teamcity, cicd, restore

i had a teamcity instance running as a simple docker container with data and logs volumes on he host maching, which for some reason started showing 404 page.
i stopped, then removed the container. and tried running a new container with the existing data and log directories aka volumes, but error occurs which states that these directories must be empty.
the problem here is that i did not take an explicit backup of the instance before removing the old containers, but i do have `data` `logs` directories intact, and i am using RDS instance to persist data in teamcity, so that is also intact and present

so is there anything that i can do to restore to my earlier version? anything will be helpful. thanks.

tried setting jvm option -teamcity.data.dir to old directory, while mapping volumes to new directory, but still am getting teamcity start page.